# Using 'back' button breaks page after POST event

Tags: php, post

There is a search function running here http://www.ssaib.co.uk/security-provider-search/ that works perfectly fine and you get a result set. However when you get the results if you choose a results and click 'more' then attempt to go 'back' the page breaks instead of resubmitting the post. Can't seem to find a mention of this anywhere.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

What are you using as a browser?

I just tested it and it works on latest Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and Internet Explorer. Once you go back, you get to the search results again.

EDIT:

You have two options.

First:

- Submit the search with GET variable instead of POST. This is much better since search engines can then crawl search results as well.

Second:

If you still want to use POST, then smart search systems get rid of the POST redirect like this:

- Form that has a target URL of "search.php" (or whatever the one you're using)
- Once submitted to search.php, you conduct a database search and assign a unique 'id' to that search
- search.php then redirects user to '/searchresults/' page (or its equivalent) that has the unique ID either in the URL (like '/searchresults/23442/') or GET variable ('/searchresults/?id=23442'). In that page, user is shown the search results that were found through search.php script.
- This means that if user clicks 'back' then they will get back to their search results page. This also has the benefit of you not having to search the database again every time user clicks 'back'. Browser never goes back to URL's that have been redirected through a header, so even if user goes back twice, it does not break anything.
- After a while you should invalidate 'old' searches from database, or re-generate them if user asks for that very same ID again.

Comment: It does appear to only be certain browsers. Not sure if there is a work around to avoid it altogether though. I figured it must be browser security flaw but didnt know if anyone knew a workaround?

Comment: Well, the main problem you have there is that something might cause a conflict in that re-submit form process. This is usually why it is a good idea to do search differently, I'll post an explanation in my original answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Added the options in the original answer.

Comment: For some reason I can't get a GET to work as the search queries an mssql stored procedure which seems to be throwing a fit whenever I use GET variables. The ID idea sounded good however the process is search>search results>indvidual page and it is going back from the individual page to the search results page that is dying so it would always be the same URL even if I was using an ID...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GET` for retrieval.  If you do use `POST`, however, you should *always* (in my opinion) use [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).  This usually requires you to use the `SESSION` to keep state between the redirect.